# How to retrieve GET parameters in Django CBV get_queryset()

Tags: django, django-views

I'm currently trying to convert my FBV function to a CBV one.

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):

        search_text = request.GET.get('search_text')
        ...
```

But, I'm already stuck with the beginning part. I need a value of `search_text` to filter my queryset afterward. When using FBV, I got inputs through `reqest.GET.get()` but it doesn't work anymore in CBV. What can replace it with?

Comment: I once got stuck in a world where I thought I should do my best to convert all my FBV's to CBV's.  I've since been taught better :D

Comment: do what comes to your mind first, the most important is to know how to do both

Answer (score 10, accepted):

get access to it with `self`:

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    ''' codes '''
    def get_queryset(self):

        search_text = self.request.GET.get('search_text')
```